# Boost 1.57.0 python example won't build

Tags: python, boost, bjam

Here is what I did:
1. Downloaded boost 1.57.0 bz2 file
2. `untar` it to a local directory
3. `cd boost_1_57_0/libs/python/example/quickstart`
4. File command as instructed by the turtorial: `bjam toolset=gcc --verbose-test test`
5. Got error:

```
$ bjam toolset=gcc --verbose-test test
```

> Unable to load Boost.Build: could not find build system.
>   --------------------------------------------------------- /home/XXX/tmp/boost_1_57_0/libs/python/example/quickstart/boost-build.jam
>   attempted to load the build system by invoking  'boost-build
>   ../../../../tools/build/v2 ;'
>
> but we were unable to find `bootstrap.jam` in the specified directory
>   or in `BOOST_BUILD_PATH` (searching `/home/XXX/tmp/boost_1_57_0/libs/python/example/quickstart/../../../../tools/build/v2`, `/usr/share/boost-build`).
>
> Please consult the documentation at http://www.boost.org.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The Boost Build directory layout has changed in a recent version, but the Boost Python quickstart example has not been updated to reflect this.

You should change the boost-build.jam file in the quickstart example to say:

```
boost-build ../../../../tools/build/src ;
```

instead of:

```
boost-build ../../../../tools/build/v2 ;
```